# Adding bitmap image as table cell background in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, winforms, bitmap, html-email

I'm struggling with a problem where I need to assign a bitmap image to a table cell. Actually I'm saving signature as image in the database and I'm getting the image data from the database, then converting it to bitmap image and successfully displaying it in the winform. I now need to display the image in a html cell when I'm generating a html email.

The code for grabbing and converting the data to bit image is as follows:

```
If Not (strucJob.ClientSignature Is Nothing) Then
    Dim imageData As Byte() = strucJob.ClientSignature
    If Not imageData Is Nothing Then
        Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        ms.Write(imageData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length))
        signature = New Bitmap(ms, False)
        ms.Dispose()
    End If
End If
```

And here I need to assign the image as cell background:

```
bodyText = bodyText & "<tr>" & _
     "<td colspan=3 align=left bgcolor = 'white' valign=top><FONT size=2>" & _
        "background: " & String.Format("background:url('{0}')", signature) & _
    "</td>" & _
    "<td align=left bgcolor = 'white' valign=top><FONT size=2>" & _
            "<b>" & singNamw & "</b>" & _
    "</td>" & _
"</tr>"
```

Here's where it is giving me trouble:

```
"<td colspan=3 align=left bgcolor = 'white' valign=top><FONT size=2>" & _
   "background: " & String.Format("background:url('{0}')", signature) & _
"</td>" & _
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"<td colspan=3 align=left style=\"" & String.Format("background-image:url('{0}');", signature) &"\"><FONT size=2></FONT></td>"
```

Use the image as background of the td like what I have above.

Comment: Hi Nikko, just tried that, no luck :-(
 "<td colspan=3 align=left style=\" & String.Format("background-image:url('{0}');", signature) & "\>" & "<FONT size=2></FONT></td>" & _

Comment: If I put exactly your code then it give me error "end of the statement expected" here at " background" <td colspan=3 align=left style=\"" & String.Format("background
because I think the double quote is giving me that error. If I put it in the this way 
<td colspan=3 align=left style=\" & String.Format("background-image:url('{0}');", signature) & "\>" & "<FONT size=2></FONT></td>"
Then, the error is gone but doesnot display any picture thought id has value

Comment: okay I am comparing your code with mine (own project). :)

can you remove the single quotes from the background-image:url()? then try again.

and also, what happens if you hard code a test url?

Comment: Hi Nik,
I really appreciate your help. removing single quote is not working. I've tried to hard code the image url like the following:
  "<td colspan=3 align=left style= background-image:url(C:\Users\rajib.das\Pictures\BE6K10.png);<FONT size=2></FONT></td>" & _
Still no luck. Now I'm feeling helpless.

Comment: Last try. Use this: :)

<td colspan="3" style="background-image:url(C:\Users\rajib.das\Pictures\BE6K10.png); width=100px;"><span>asdasd</span></td>